# 'Type' is used like a Variable (c#)

Tags: c#, wpf, list, compiler-errors

I've run into the following compiler error, and am not sure what to do about this:

> System.Windows.Document.List is a 'Type' bus is used like a 'variable'

This is the code the message is from:

```
public blabla this[int index]
{
    get {return (blabla)List(Index);}
    set {List(Index) = value;}
}
```

I wrote this code in VB, and am trying to get this to work in c# any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What do you try to do with `List(Index)..` ?

Comment: Set the current value of "value"  to the index of the selected list

Comment: Then you need to use `[]`

Comment: @BartTeunissen: What do you *expect* `List` to mean here? Do you have a property called `List` that you're trying to access? You haven't provided nearly enough context here. If you could provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, that would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: @jon skeet , It was a syntax error (which is suspected). Thats why i thought this much info/code was sufficient, and hence the problem was solved :) Thanks for your response :)

Comment: @BartTeunissen: No, that's not sufficient because we don't know what `List` is meant to refer to. Context is everything. Even if *you've* now got your answer, it's not nearly as useful to future visitors as it would be if you'd provide more context.

Comment: Jon Skeet is right @BartTeunissen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# accessing Collection specific item is this way:

```
List[Index]
```

in VB:

```
List(Index)
```

Check [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132434%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)